# How to send 'print' key with RDC (Remote Desktop Connection)?

Tags: remote-control, keyboard

I use Microsoft's RDC on Mac. I need to click on print key to have some screen capture, but Mac Keyboard doesn't have one.

How do I send print key with Mac through RDC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The MS RDC has a preference menu so that you can customize the shortcuts.

Comment: i am using RDC from the App Store on my MBA. I don't see this preference dialog in MS' RDC client. Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Try <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>- it worked for me!

Comment: that is the equivalent of "Alt+F4" on windows. This closes a window. Is this a troll ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the virtual keyboard windows has under the "accessibility" programs menu

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

It worked for me! (I'm using rdesktop on Linux > Windows Server 2012 R2, with -K option).

Answer (score -2):

The print screen command on a Mac is:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

So on Windows it would most likely be:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, but you can't just take any Mac command, change every ⌘ to ^, and *guess* that that is probably how it works on Windows. Such speculative answers are not useful.